# hide custom header in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using custom header in category tableview. So, in accordance to that condition, I have to hide header and it's detail.  So, I used following code for displaying header with condition.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *aView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];


    if(section==0)
    {


        if(![appDelegate.purchase_requisitions_preference isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![appDelegate.purchase_requisitions_preference isEqualToString:@"null"])
        {

            UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
            btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:33.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
            [btn setTag:section+1];
            UILabel *label1  =  [[UILabel alloc]init];
            label1.frame     =  CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 30);
            label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

            label1.text = @"Purchase Order Requisitions";
            [label1 setTag:section+1];
            [btn addSubview:label1];
            [aView addSubview:btn];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        }
        else
        {
            return nil;
        }


    }
    else if(section==1)
    {

        if(![appDelegate.hr_vacancies_preference isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![appDelegate.hr_vacancies_preference isEqualToString:@"null"])
        {

            UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
            btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:33.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
            [btn setTag:section+1];
            UILabel *label1  =  [[UILabel alloc]init];
            label1.frame     =  CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 30);
            label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

            label1.text = @"Human Resource Vacancies";
            [label1 setTag:section+1];
            [btn addSubview:label1];
            [aView addSubview:btn];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        }
        else
        {
            return nil;
        }


    }
    else  if(section==2)
    {

        if(![appDelegate.hr_offers_preference isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![appDelegate.hr_offers_preference isEqualToString:@"null"])
        {
            NSLog(@"in offer");

            UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
            btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:39.0/255.0 green:131.0/255.0 blue:33.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
            [btn setTag:section+1];
            UILabel *label1  =  [[UILabel alloc]init];
            label1.frame     =  CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 30);
            label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

            label1.text = @"Human Resource Job Offers";
            [label1 setTag:section+1];
            [btn addSubview:label1];
            [aView addSubview:btn];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sectionTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        }
        else
        {

            return nil;
        }

    }
    return aView;
}
```

If my condition is false, then I want to hide my header as well as it's detail. Its detail is getting hide but header is still displaying there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return 0` in `heightForHeaderInSection:` method if your Data is nil otherwise return 30( just example) like bellow..

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section==0)
    {
        if(![appDelegate.purchase_requisitions_preference isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![appDelegate.purchase_requisitions_preference isEqualToString:@"null"])
        {
          return 30;// any height which you want        
        }
        else{
          return 0;
        }
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Height of Header Section,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section==0 | section==1 |section==2)
        return 30;
    else
        return 0;
}
```